# TFS/MSBuild breaks on static content after implementing Incremental Builds

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild

To speed up building we’ve switched to incremental builds. A described in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833876%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), I’ve added the following information to my build project:

```
   <PropertyGroup>
      <SkipClean>true</SkipClean>
      <SkipInitializeWorkspace>true</SkipInitializeWorkspace>
      <ForceGet>false</ForceGet>
   </PropertyGroup>
```

All worked fine and building goes A LOT faster. Lately I've been getting these types of errors that break my build:

> [Any CPU/Release] C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(60,3):
>   error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "IMAGES\tab\black.gif" to
>   "D:\Build\Binaries\Release_PublishedWebsites\MyApp\IMAGES\tab\black.gif".
>   Access to the path
>   'D:\Build\Binaries\Release_PublishedWebsites\MyApp\IMAGES\tab\black.gif'
>   is denied.

This problem occurs only *sometimes*. It is **never a dll** (as on other question on SO), but always a .gif or a .css file (static content). How is it possible the these type of files are getting locked?

<sub>Deleting the temp binary directory solves the problem for the next build... but that doesn't feel like a right solution.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problems with our builds but we do not perform incremental builds.

The workaround for the issue I came up with is to edit your Build Definition and set the **Clean Workspace** option (in **Process** > **2. Basic**) to **Outputs** (from None) this should prevent it from happening and. This didn't add too much overhead to our builds, but they are done on SSD's.

I think it is an issue with some files getting copied over with a read-only flag still set on them, but have never been able to figure it out.

Comment: This is not a workaround because you disabled incremental build. If you set workspace option to Outputs, Clean target is called on all projects before build and your projects needs to be build again. Output option is useful for builds used for deploys - changes are get incrementally and projects are rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have multiple website projects in your solution. Every website is published to the same D:\Build\Binaries\Release_PublishedWebsites\MyApp folder. You are using the same image names in two or more websites as a content. When these website projects are build in parallel, websites are sometimes build at the same time. One website project is trying to copy its content to the output folder while other website project is already copying the same content to the target folder.

Comment: That was my initial thought exactly, but I have no shared resources between web-apps (only dlls, but they never fail). I didn't configure my project to build in parallel and I'm not sure if it builds that way by default.

Comment: You can have shared resources between websites when you are using the same reference and referenced project contain some content files. Content files are copied to the website output folder together with referenced dll. Can you try to build your websites to different folders? Then you can check if only one website is using images folder.